# Resume file downloading with Spring Webflux and static files serving in Spring

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I belive there is no answear in the whole internet for this as it is probably very complex but I will go ahead and ask.

Basically, I want to have a cross communication between multiple Spring applications. Each of them is serving resources in a static way, [here is the link for that topic](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources). This serving is capitalized by other application instances that can download those files on request (for now I am transferring files via HTTP). I was able to download files thanks to the [Downlolad and save file from ClientRequest using ExchangeFunction in Project Reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091069/downlolad-and-save-file-from-clientrequest-using-exchangefunction-in-project-rea) SO question.

Right now I want to elevate my code so that in case of the connection issue or application being temporarily unavailable for the given timeout I am able to **resume** the downloading of the file. I configured the `WebClient` timeouts as in [this article](https://medium.com/@senanayake.kalpa/configuring-timeouts-in-spring-reactive-webclient-4bc5faf56411).

Right now, I thought that such code would actually let me handle temporarily unavailable services:

```
final AsynchronousFileChannel fileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(targetPath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);

Flux<DataBuffer> fileData = Mono.just(filePath)
    .map(file -> targetPath.toFile().exists() ? targetPath.toFile().length() : 0)
    .map(bytes -> webClient
            .get()
            .uri(uri)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("Range", String.format("bytes=%d-", bytes))
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new CustomException("4xx error")))
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new CustomException("5xx error")))
            .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
    )
    .flatMapMany(Function.identity());

DataBufferUtils
        .write(fileData , fileChannel)
        .map(DataBufferUtils::release)
        .doOnError(throwable -> {
            try {
                fileChannel.force(true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
        .retry(3)
        .doOnComplete(() -> {
            try {
                fileChannel.force(true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
        .doOnError(e -> !(e instanceof ChannelException), e -> {
            try {
                Files.deleteIfExists(targetPath);
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
        .doOnError(ChannelException.class, e -> {
            try {
                Files.deleteIfExists(targetPath);
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
        .doOnTerminate(() -> {
            try {
                fileChannel.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
    .blockLast();
```

But apparently I am getting a full stack of errors whenever I kill my second instance of application starting with:

```
reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response
2019-10-25T15:41:53.602+0200 [ERROR] [xxx] [N/A:N/A] [r.core.publisher.Operators] { thread=reactor-http-nio-4  } Operator called default onErrorDropped
reactor.core.Exceptions$BubblingException: reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.bubble(Exceptions.java:154)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.onErrorDropped(Operators.java:512)
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundError(FluxReceive.java:343)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundError(ChannelOperations.java:399)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundClose(HttpClientOperations.java:258)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelInactive(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:121)
```

and also later in the same stack trace:

```
2019-10-25T15:41:53.602+0200 [WARN] [xxx] [N/A:N/A] [i.n.c.AbstractChannelHandlerContext] { thread=reactor-http-nio-4  } An exception 'reactor.core.Exceptions$BubblingException: reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response' [enable DEBUG level for full stacktrace] was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:
reactor.core.Exceptions$BubblingException: reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.bubble(Exceptions.java:154)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.onErrorDropped(Operators.java:512)
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundError(FluxReceive.java:343)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundError(ChannelOperations.java:399)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundClose(HttpClientOperations.java:258)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelInactive(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:121)
```

The exceptions itself are not much of a problem but **the point being is that my download does not resume after I boot my application back up to live.**

So yeah, my question is, how could I possibly resume the downloading and how should/could I handle such exceptions as in here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code had 2 issues. First of them was the way of determining how big the file is at the start. The correct way to to use `AtomicLong` just as in `DataBufferUtils.write()`. Second issue was the `retry()` between remote calls. It seems like a good fashion to use `retryWhen()` when dealing with remote calls with a fixed backoff. Just to sum this up, here is the code which enabled me resuming file downloading from the correct byte in case of connection/application issue

```
final AsynchronousFileChannel fileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(targetPath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);

AtomicLong fileSize = new AtomicLong(targetPath.toFile().length());

Flux<DataBuffer> fileDataStream = webClient
                .get()
                .uri(remoteXFerServiceTargetHost)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .header("Range", String.format("bytes=%d-", fileSize.get()))
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new CustomException("4xx error")))
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new CustomException("5xx error")))
                .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);

DataBufferUtils
        .write(fileData , fileChannel)
        .map(DataBufferUtils::release)
        .doOnError(throwable -> {
            try {
                fileChannel.force(true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
        .retryWhen(Retry.any().fixedBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).retryMax(5))
        .doOnComplete(() -> {
            try {
                fileChannel.force(true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
        .doOnError(e -> !(e instanceof ChannelException), e -> {
            try {
                Files.deleteIfExists(targetPath);
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
        .doOnError(ChannelException.class, e -> {
            try {
                Files.deleteIfExists(targetPath);
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
        .doOnTerminate(() -> {
            try {
                fileChannel.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
    .blockLast();
```

Comment: should be DataBufferUtils .write(fileDataStream, fileChannel) instead of DataBufferUtils .write(fileData , fileChannel)?

Comment: Yes. I made a typo back then when formatting the code.

Comment: Doesn't `blockLast` defeat the `reactive` framework. Some aggregated `epoll` like [EpollEventLoop extends SingleThreadEventLoop](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/090e9a727196d60af3f463a13762e8bdb697c1f1/transport-native-epoll/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/epoll/EpollEventLoop.java#L320) might help increase throughput for web crawlers. If it is an occasional one time download, not sure if reactive is a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

Hi following is the implementation I found [Spring-webflux-file-upload-download](https://ddcode.net/2019/06/21/spring-webflux-file-upload-and-download/)

and based on it following is my code for file download:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class DownloadContorller {

    @GetMapping
    public Mono<Void> downloadByWriteWith(ServerHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage zeroCopyResponse = (ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage) response;
        response.getHeaders().set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=large-file.so");
        response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("large-file.so");
        File file = resource.getFile();
        return zeroCopyResponse.writeWith(file, 0, file.length());
    }
}
```

I have tested it using `wget -c http://localhost:8080/` and I am able to **resume** the download from where it got interrupted. I tested it by

1. Interrupting from client-side (Ctrl+C) on the terminal
2. Stopping the application and then restarting it.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Well, maybe, but sadly this is not reactive style kind of programming. This piece of code does not consider any exception handling or anything related to it which is essential.

Comment: This is reactive, as returning Mono and there is no blocking operation in between, it will give you event loop, Also it's a cleaner way not to write, exception handling in the same place as your code, it's recommended that you do it in controller advice https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-controller-advice . Lastly, your way of writing code is functional, code  mentioned in the solution is imperative, but both are reactive. Spring reactive supports both. Thanks.

Comment: since when is .getFile() non blocking? I agree that this code is not reactive and blocking

Answer (score 0):

Other way: get an entire file as `Mono<String>`. Than map this to `byte[]` and invoke standart `FileUtils` methods.

On examle I need to download file by endpoint and save this:

Service for downlad file:
`@GetMapping
Mono<String> getEventFile();`

Get and save to file path:

```
return getEventFile().map( text -> text.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) )
    .doOnNext(file -> FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile( new File( savePath ), file ) )
...
```

Don't forget about exceptions.